# Lubrication Theory Cylinder approaching a wall

Tags: fluid-dynamics

In my lecture notes, we went through a problem with a cylinder approaching a stationary wall with speed $v$. Since we are interested in the thin layer approximation, we utilised lubrication theory. Approximating the distance between the cylinder and wall as

$h(x) = d(1+x^2/2ad)$

where $d$ is the shortest distance between the cylinder and wall.

To find the flow velocity $u$, we used the parallel flow equations to get:

$u=1/2\mu (dp/dx)y(h-y)$

But what i don't understand is why we have imlemented the boundary conditions that the flow velocity is 0 and both $y=0$ and $y=h$, surely, the velocity should be $-v%$ at $y=h$?

Comment: This isn't really a math question. I think you'll have better luck at https://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is hard to answer without your notes (you should probably ask your professor) but using $-v$ at $y=h$ sounds reasonable to me, depending on the specifics of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The cylinder is moving so it is also a function of time. The velocity is a vector usually denoted $\vec{v}$ or $\vec{u} = (u,v,w)$ where $u = \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}$ $v = \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$. The boundary conditions would require,
\begin{cases} 
      u=0 & \text{ at } y=0, y=h(x,t) \\
      v=0 & \text{ at } y=0\\
      v=\frac{dh}{dt} & \text{ at } y=h(x,t)\\
   \end{cases}